# Any hint about solving this monster determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm asked to solve the following determinant:
$$|A|=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 &2 &3 &\cdots &{n-1} &n\\
2 &3 &4 &\cdots &n &1\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & &\vdots &\vdots\\
{n-1} &n &1 &\cdots &{n-3} &{n-2}\\
n &1 &2 &\cdots &{n-2} &{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}
$$
My attempt is to add all the other columns onto the first one, which gives
$$|A|=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}|B|$$
where $|B|$ is, however, none the easier than $|A|$.
I think the result should be very special, since $A$ is a very special symmetric matrix itself. But I simply get stuck. Can you help me? thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT** 
It just occurred to me that definition might work out well here. Am I on the right track?
I'm now into another question. If $(j_1,j_2,\cdots,j_n)$ is an $n-th$ permutation of ${1,2,\cdots,n}$ and the number of inversion pairs in there is $\tau$, then what's the number of inversion pairs in its inverse permutation $(j_n,j_{n-1},\cdots,j_2,j_1)$ ? This may shed a light on the problem.
Some friend of mine has given me a relatively simple solution, which I will add subsequently  as an answer.

Comment: i don't know if it helps, but $n(n+1)/2$ is an eigenvalue and the eigenvector is $(1,1,\cdots, 1).$

Comment: "I think eigenvalues won't have a role to play in the value of the determinant" --- you might want to reflect on this a moment.

Comment: Up to a sign, I get $n^{n-2}  (n^2 + n)/2$

Comment: @WillO Sorry I was being a little flippant. I know if we know **all** the eigenvalues we can know the det immediately. But only **one** eigenvalue  seems to be of little help..

Comment: i experimented with the determinant and i found that the determinant  is $n(n+1)/2\left(n^{n-2}\right)$ except for the sign. agree with what will reported.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A052182

Comment: @WillO I'll be glad to see more details..

Comment: @abel So you mean $|B|=n^{n-2}$?

Comment: the absolute value of the determinant of $B$ is $n^{n-2}.$ the determinant of $B$ is negative for $n = 2, 4, 6, \cdots.$

Comment: [See theorem 17 on page 23 of this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes**

The approach in *method 1* seems a little bit overkill for this problem.
I have added another approach (*method 2*) based on row/column operations.
I hope that will be more accessible.

---

**Method 1** (inspired by Fourier transform on a circular lattice.)

Let $A$ be any $n \times n$ matrix whose entries has the form
$$A_{ij} = a_{i+j},\quad 0 \le i, j < n$$
where $( a_k )$ is a periodic sequence of length $n$. Let $\phi_A(z)$ be
the polynomial:

$$\phi_A(z) = \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} a_s z^s$$

Let $\displaystyle\;\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}\;$ be the $n^{th}$ root of unity. Let $\Omega$ and $\Delta$ be two $n \times n$ matrices defined by

$$\Omega_{ij} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\omega^{ij}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\Delta_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1, & i + j \equiv 0, \pmod n\\
0, & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

It is clear
$$( \Omega^\dagger\Omega )_{ij} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \bar{\omega}^{ki}\omega^{kj} 
= \frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega^{k(j-i)} = \delta_{ij} = (I_n)_{ij},\quad 0 \le i,j < n$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. This implies $\Omega^\dagger\Omega = I_n$ and $\Omega$ is an unitary matrix.

Notice
$$
( \Omega^\dagger A O )_{ij}
= \frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \bar{\omega}^{ki} a_{k+l} \omega^{lj}
= \phi_A(\omega^j)
  \left( \frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \omega^{-k(i+j)}\right)
= \phi_A(\omega^j) \Delta_{ij}
$$ 
This leads to
$$\det(A) = \det(\Delta) \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \phi_A(\omega_j)
= (-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}} \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \phi_A(\omega_j)$$

For our case, $a_s = s+1$ for $0 \le s < n$ and

$$\phi_A(z) = 1 + 2z + 3z^2 + nz^{n-1} = \left(\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}\right)'
= -(n+1)\frac{z^n}{1-z} + \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{(1-z)^2}$$

This implies

$$\phi_A(\omega^j) = 
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\;\frac{n(n+1)}{2}, & j = 0\\
\\
\displaystyle\;-\frac{n}{1-\omega^j}, & 1 \le j < n
\end{cases}$$

As a result,
$$\det(A) = (-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}}
\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)(-n)^{n-1}\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{1-\omega^j}\right)$$

Notice $$\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (z-\omega^j) = \frac{z^n-1}{z-1} = 1 + z + \cdots + z^{n-1}$$
We get
$$\det(A) = \frac12 (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} (n+1)n^{n-1}$$

Up to a sign, this is the same as the OEIS sequence [A052182](https://oeis.org/A052182). The difference comes form the way one shift the rows. The one on
OEIS are for matrices whose successive rows are shifted/rotated to right while
the one for this problem is shifted/rotated to the left.

---

**Method 2** (based on row/column operations)

For any $n > 2$, consider following three $n \times n$ matrices. $D_n, L_n$ are lower triangular while $R_n$ is upper triangle.

$$(D_n)_{ij} = \begin{cases}
+1, & i = j\\
-1, & i = j+1\\
 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
,\quad
(L_n)_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1, & i = j\\
1, & i > 2 \land j = 2\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\
(R_n)_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1, & i = j\\
1, & j = n\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
For example, for $n = 5$, we have

$$D_5 = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
,
\quad
L_5 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
R_5 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

It is clear the determinants of all these matrices are one.

1. If we multiply $A$ by $R_n$ from the left, the effect is summing all $n$ columns and place the results into last columns.
2. If we multiply $AR_n$ by $D_n$ from the right, the effect is

   - subtract the $(n-1)^{th}$ row form the $n^{th}$ row.
   - subtract the $(n-2)^{th}$ row from the $(n-1)^{th}$ row.
   - $\quad\quad\vdots$
   - subtract the $2^{nd}$ row from the $1^{st}$ row.

   The result is

   - the $1^{st}$ row remains untouhced.
   - aside from the first row, the $n^{th}$ column of every other row becomes $0$.
   - aside from the first row, most entries on every other row becomes $1$.
     In particular, all entries (except the last entry) in $2^{nd}$ row is $1$.
3. If we multiply $D_n A R_n$ by $L_n$ from the left, the effect is

   - subtract the $2^{nd}$ row from all rows below it.

   Since most entries there are $1$, the final effect is on $3^{rd}$ to last row,
   there is one any only one entries remain for each row.

The resulting matrix look like this:

$$L_n D_n A R_n = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1 & \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1   &   1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0   &  -n & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -n  &   0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 &  0 & -n & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -n & 0  & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
From this, we find
$$\begin{align}
\det(A) 
&= \det(L_n D_n A R_n)\\
&= 
\overbrace{
(-1)^{n-1} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
}^{\color{blue}{
\text{from expanding } 1^{st} \text{ row}
}}
\times 
\overbrace{
(-1)^{\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{2}}
}^{\color{blue}{
\text{from flipping } 2^{nd} \text{ to } (n-1)^{th} \text{row}
}}
\times
(-n)^{n-2}\\
&= \frac12 (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} (n+1)n^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is symmetric and therefore has $n$ orthogonal real eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n$ and we have $\det A=\lambda_1\cdot\ldots\cdot \lambda_n$. Guessing eigenvectors might help. Unfortunately this guessing  (apart from the "all ones" vector)  is only really simple in the complexification:

If $\zeta\in\mathbb C$ is an $n$th root of unity, let $v_\zeta:=(1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\ldots,\zeta^{n-1})^T$.
Observe from the fact that multiplication by $\zeta$ rotates $v_\zeta$ componentwise that $$Av_\zeta=(1+2\zeta+\ldots+n\zeta^{n-1})\cdot v_{\zeta^{-1}}.$$
Hence $v_\zeta$ is an eigenvector of $A^2$ with eigenvalue  $|1+2\zeta+\ldots+n\zeta^{n-1}|^2$. Since the $v_\zeta$ are linearly independant, we conclude that 
$$(\det A)^2= \prod_{\zeta^n=1}|1+2\zeta+\ldots+n\zeta^{n-1}|^2$$
hence
$$\tag1\det A =\pm \prod_{\zeta^n=1} |1+2\zeta+\ldots+n\zeta^{n-1}|$$
Let's simplify: 
We have
$$ \tag2(1+2\zeta+\ldots+n\zeta^{n-1})(1-\zeta)=1+\zeta+\ldots+\zeta^{n-1}-n$$
and 
$$ \tag3(1+\zeta+\ldots+\zeta^{n-1})(1-\zeta)=1-\zeta^n=0.$$
If $\zeta=1$ then clearly $1+2\zeta+\ldots+n\zeta^{n-1}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. In all other cases, $(2)$ and $(3)$ imply $$(1+2\zeta+\ldots+n\zeta^{n-1})=\frac n{\zeta-1}.$$
Since the $\zeta-1$ with $\zeta^n=1$ and $\zeta\ne 1$ are precisely the roots of the polynomial $$\frac{(X+1)^n-1}{X}=X^{n-1}+\ldots + n$$
we conclude that $n=(-1)^{n-1}\prod_{\zeta^n=1,\zeta\ne 1}(\zeta-1)$.
Therefore $(1)$ becomes
$$|\det A|=\left|\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\cdot \frac{n^{n-1}}{\prod_{\zeta^n=1, \zeta\ne 1}(\zeta-1)}\right|=\frac{n^{n-1}(n+1)}{2}.$$

I am still fighting with the sign of $\det A$, though ...

Comment: Thanks! But I have trouble following this part: $$Av_\zeta=(1+2\zeta+\ldots+n\zeta^{n-1})\cdot v_{\zeta^{-1}}.$$ I understand why multiplication by ζ rotates vζ componentwise, but cannot figure out how you get that equation from this fact?

Comment: The sign appears to be $(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of looking at the $\det(A)$:
by swapping pairs of rows $(1,n-1),(2,n-2)\dots$
this matrix is transformed into 
circulant matrix $C$ with the same $0$-th row $(1,\dots,n)$,
which has a well known explicit formula for determinant,
\begin{align}
\det(C)&=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+1)\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{jk}{n}\right).
\end{align}
Accounting to the number of swapped rows,
\begin{align}
\det(A)&=(-1)^{\lfloor (n+3)/2\rfloor}\det(C).
\end{align}
And as @Michael Biro has pointed out in the comment,
[A052182](https://oeis.org/A052182) gives 
\begin{align}
\det(C)&=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n+1)n^{n-1}}{2},
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align}
\det(A)&=(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{(n+1)n^{n-1}}{2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine has given me a relatively easy solution as follows. ( Apologies that I'm on the mobile device so it's not convenient to code)
[image]

Well, I just uploaded the picture from my PC. It looks okay now :)

Comment: By the way it is the same as @achille hui 's method2, but may be easier to follow.

Comment: +1 it is now readable and does clearly show all those steps that is hard to typeset.

Comment: This is slick !